# Inserting into a table if a select query returns 0 rows

Tags: sql, database, mariadb

I want to insert a new row into a database table, only if a condition is met beforehand.

**Context**
MariaDB Database, 10.3.38-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

This is my table:

```
+-----------+-------------+------+
| sender_id | receiver_id | col3 |
+-----------+-------------+------+
```

Where sender_id and receiver_id are both 16 byte foreign key columns, and col3 is a boolean.

- This table tracks a relationship between two users, the id columns represent a 16-byte UUID.
- Users can request to insert a new relationship between themselves and another user in the table.
- The uuid of the user who initiates the relationship is placed in column: sender_id, and the uuid of the user they want to bond with is placedin column: receiver_id.

**The Issue**
Whenever a user attempts to create a new relationship, the database must check whether they already have a relationship, AND ensure that another relationship with their uuid values swapped between columns doesn't exist.

For example:
If the database looked like this,

```
+-----------+-------------+------+
| sender_id | receiver_id | col3 |
+-----------+-------------+------+
|  user 1   |    user 2   | true |
+-----------+-------------+------+
```

Suppose user 2 attempts to initiate a NEW relationship with user 1.
In that case, the database would look like this.

```
+-----------+-------------+------+
| sender_id | receiver_id | col3 |
+-----------+-------------+------+
|  user 1   |    user 2   | true |
+-----------+-------------+------+
|  user 2   |    user 1   | true |
+-----------+-------------+------+
```

How can I prevent the user from inserting a new row, even though it's technically different in this case?

**What I Tried**
I tried to use an IF statement in conjunction with a SELECT query to check if any rows matching my parameters existed, and if not, inserting the row; however it threw an SQL error..

**Limitations**
I want to use the fewest amount of SQL statements as possible.
Preferably, only a single statement should be sent.

I am a novice with SQL, and I have been scratching my head over this problem for a while. If any of you clever folks can help me find a solution, I would be eternally grateful..

Comment: since it seems like you don't actually care which is sender_id and which receiver_id, the easiest way to do this is to always sort before doing the insert so sender_id is less than receiver_id, and do insert ignore.

Comment: @ysth ... and then maybe add a unique key on `(sender_id, receiver_id)`.

Comment: do note that if you sort the sender_id/receiver_id to avoid duplication, then the names of those columns won't really be accurate, and you will not know which user actually initiated the relationship

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a derived, uniquely-constrained column that tracks the unique combination of the two users as "user1-user2", where user1 is the "lowest" user and user2 is the "highest":

```
create table mytable (
  sender_id text,
  receiver_id text,
  col3 text, 
  combo_key text not null
    default concat(least(sender_id, receiver_id), '-', greatest(sender_id, receiver_id))
    unique
)
```

See [live demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/T3DjsaTd).

Attemtping to insert a logical duplicate will throw a "duplicate entry" exception.

The dash (could be anything) is added between the user strings to differentiate between user pair "abc" & "de" from "ab" & "cde".

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I am going to use this solution. However, in my case, both UUIDs are guaranteed to be the same length, so in that case, is the separator between the two id's in the combo_key col necessary?

Comment: @leo No problem; we're here to help. You are correct: The separator is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Select and insert based on the result of the select is a "check and do" pattern. This is open to [race conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition) if two users try to select and insert at the same time. They both check, see there is no row, and then both try to insert: one will fail.

You can get around this with things like transactions and [`select for update`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/for-update/), but this involves careful coding and locks which could lead to deadlock.

It's better to "do then check" in one step. This is ["atomic"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearizability) meaning it is a single operation which cannot be interrupted.

1. Set up constraints so it is impossible to add a duplicate.
2. Do the insert.
3. If there is a conflict, only update the 3rd column.

There's a couple ways to set up the constraint.

The simplest and most robust is to use two [unique indexes](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/getting-started-with-indexes/#unique-index), one on `(sender_id, receiver_id)` and one on `(receiver_id, sender_id)`. That covers both cases. This lets you preserve the sender/receiver order.

The other is to use a single unique index on `(sender_id, receiver_id)` and add a [constraint](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/constraint/) requiring that the sender_id is always less than the receiver_id (or vice versa): `check(sender_id < receiver_id)`. This also ensures they are not the same. Then in the insert logic, reorder the arguments so the users are always inserted in the correct order. You can do this in the insert statement using [if()](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/if-function/) (simpler), or you can use a [before insert and before update triggers](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-trigger/) to automatically do the reordering (more robust). Because you're reordering the arguments it is no longer clear which was the sender and receiver. You may want to rename the columns to something more generic like `user1` and `user2`.

Finally, use [on duplicate key update](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/insert-on-duplicate-key-update/) to set the 3rd column (if that's what you want).

```
insert into relationships (sender_id, receiver_id, col3) values
  (
   if('user1' < 'user2', 'user1', 'user2'),
   if('user1' > 'user2', 'user1', 'user2'),
   true
  )
on duplicate key update col3=true
```

[Demonstration](https://dbfiddle.uk/sl0dUZGT).

Answer (score 0):

Is the "relationship" symmetrical?  If so, you don't need both rows, and it might be better to store the pair canonically.

```
INSERT INTO mytable
    VALUES (sender_id, receiver_id, col3)
    LEAST(?, ?), GREATEST(?, ?), ?
```

Tack on something like this to do `INSERT` for a new pair, or an `UPDATE` for  an existing pair:

```
    ON DUPLICATE KEY col3 = NEW.col3;
```

(see "IODKU" or "upsert")

This requires `PRIMARY KEY(sender_id, receiver_id)` so that it can decide between `INSERT` and `UPDATE`.

A lookup would still need two fetches, either with `OR` or with `UNION ALL`.

```
SELECT col3
    FROM mytable
    WHERE sender_id = LEAST(?,?)  OR  receiver_id = GREATEST(?,?)
```

(And `INDEX(receiver_id)` is needed.)

(`LEAST/GREATEST(?,?)` could be pre-computed in your app.)